# Duplicate navigation when using "includes" with Jade/Node

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a one page website that I would like to keep but I also need individual sections to be viewed as independent pages. I'm using Jade with Node and everything is working fine until I start including files/blocks.

*base.jade*

```
!!! 5
  head
  body
    .nav
      // menu
    block content
```

*index.jade*

```
extends layout/base

block content
  p
   | This is the index page.
  include about
```

*about.jade*

```
extends layout/base

block content
  p
   | This is the about page.
```

What I'm trying to do is use the index page to display all of my pages and then have the individual pages extend the `base.jade` file. What's happening is I'm getting multiple navigation bars on `index.jade` because I'm extending `base.jade` twice. I'm a little stuck and feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file you include should only have the content portion such as

about-content.jade

```
p
   | This is the something about the site.
```

then index.jade is

```
extends layout/base

block content
  p
   | This is the index page.
  include about-content
```

and about.jade

```
extends layout/base

block content
  p
   | This is the about page.
  include about-content
```

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I knew I was off by a step.

Comment: I was running into a similar problem with duplication. My issue was that in my "child" jade file I was using "append {blockname}" instead of just "block {blockname}".